# Kendo Grid Autocomplete selected id while creating new item

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-autocomplete

Is it possible to get selected id for autocomplete is Kendo Autocomplete, or does it just return the value or selectedtext.

I am trying to use kendo grid along with auto complete. Everything is ok, however I am not sure how to get selected id, it just returns the text.

Comment: Could you make [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [telerik dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/)?

Comment: See http://jsbin.com/nanuvihune/1/edit?html,output

Comment: This helps when its all by itself.. how do we handle when its in the kendo grid?

Comment: here the gist https://gist.run/?id=044eb9f42fbde7e57df0d8b92c58a455